# SQL to query a table only if the table contains data

Tags: sql, mysql

This query below is running but I would like to add this extra condition; run this query only if there is data in the table STAGE.LAB.DATA.
I tried CASE and IF THEN, but I can't get it to work. Please help. What syntax should be added? Thanks

```
SELECT *
 FROM
 ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA A
  WHERE (A.HOT_TEMP_VALUE >= 118 AND A.HOT_TEMP_VALUE <= 122) ) AS result)
   WHERE RESULT !='TRUE';

IF
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA >1
 THEN
 SELECT *
 FROM
 ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA A
 WHERE (A.HOT_TEMP_VALUE >= 118 AND A.HOT_TEMP_VALUE <= 122) ) AS result)
 WHERE RESULT !='TRUE';
 ELSE
  END IF
```

Comment: a query either runs or it does not (though you can return 0 rows or not return some rows based on some condition).  please edit your question to show cases of sample data and desired results for that sample data illustrating what you mean?

Comment: are you running this in a stored program.(procedure/event/trigger/function) dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html  ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, I'll look into this further and get back to you if I have more questions

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a query result as a value, you have to put it in parentheses:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA) >= 1
THEN 
    ...
END IF
```

`IF` statements can only be used in stored programs. In an ordinary query, you can use `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM otherTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA)
```

This will return an empty result if there's nothing in `STAGE.LAB.DATA`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, I'll look into this further and get back to you if I have more questions

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA) THEN 
  ...
END IF
```

```
SELECT ...
  ...
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM STAGE.LAB.DATA)
  ...
```

EXISTS stops table scanning after first matched row is found. Rather than COUNT()..

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, I'll look into this further and get back to you if I have more questions